# Copy subset of xml input using xslt

Tags: xslt, copy, nodes

I need an XSLT file to transform input xml to another with a subset of nodes in the input xml. For ex, if input has 10 nodes, I need to create output with about 5 nodes
Input

```
  <Department diffgr:id="Department1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <Department>10</Department>
    <DepartmentDescription>BABY PRODUCTS</DepartmentDescription>
    <DepartmentSeq>7</DepartmentSeq>
    <InsertDateTime>2011-09-29T13:19:28.817-05:00</InsertDateTime>
   </Department>
```

Output:

```
  <Department diffgr:id="Department1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <Department>10</Department>
    <DepartmentDescription>BABY PRODUCTS</DepartmentDescription>
   </Department>
```

I found one way to suppress nodes that we dont need
XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Department/DepartmentSeq"/>
  <xsl:template match="Department/InsertDateTime"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need an xslt that helps me select the nodes I need and not "copy all and filter out what I dont need", since i may have to change my xslt whenever input schema adds more nodes.

Update:

The snippet I sent was from a .NET Diffgram. The complete xml is as follows

Input:

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
  <NewDataSet>
    <MessageHeader>
      <MessageID>201112270242029525719b93a-5fc5-42ce-8424-10764a4497ca</MessageID>
      <RequestType>Publish</RequestType>
      <ListOfApplications />
      <MessageType>MCH</MessageType>
    </MessageHeader>
    <Department diffgr:id="Department1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
      <Department>10</Department>
      <DepartmentDescription>BABY PRODUCTS</DepartmentDescription>
      <DepartmentSeq>7</DepartmentSeq>
      <InsertDateTime>2011-09-29T13:19:28.817-05:00</InsertDateTime>
      <UpdateDateTime>2011-09-30T11:50:59-05:00</UpdateDateTime>
      <InsertDateTimeUTC>2011-09-29T18:19:28.817-05:00</InsertDateTimeUTC>
    </Department>
    <Subclass diffgr:id="Subclass1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="modified">
      <Department>10</Department>
      <Category>03</Category>
      <Class>010</Class>
      <Subclass>03</Subclass>
      <SubclassLongDescription>BABY ACCESSORIES-OTHER LD TX 1120</SubclassLongDescription>
      <SubclassShortDescription>BABY ACCESSORIES-OTH</SubclassShortDescription>
    </Subclass>
  </NewDataSet>
  <diffgr:before>
    <Subclass diffgr:id="Subclass1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
      <Department>10</Department>
      <Category>03</Category>
      <Class>010</Class>
      <Subclass>03</Subclass>
      <SubclassLongDescription>BABY ACCESSORIES-OTHER LD TX 1120</SubclassLongDescription>
      <SubclassShortDescription>BABY ACCESSORIES-OTH</SubclassShortDescription>
    </Subclass>
  </diffgr:before>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

With the xslt Borodin provided, heres what I get

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <NewDataSet>
    <MessageHeader>
      <MessageID>201112270242029525719b93a-5fc5-42ce-8424-10764a4497ca</MessageID>
      <RequestType>Publish</RequestType>
      <ListOfApplications />
      <MessageType>MCH</MessageType>
    </MessageHeader>
    <Department diffgr:id="Department1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
      <Department>10</Department>
      <DepartmentDescription>BABY PRODUCTS</DepartmentDescription>
    </Department>
    <Subclass diffgr:id="Subclass1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="modified">
      <Department>10</Department>
      <Category>03</Category>
      <Class>010</Class>
      <Subclass>03</Subclass>
      <SubclassLongDescription>BABY ACCESSORIES-OTHER LD TX 1120</SubclassLongDescription>
      <SubclassShortDescription>BABY ACCESSORIES-OTH</SubclassShortDescription>
    </Subclass>
  </NewDataSet>
  <diffgr:before>
    <Subclass diffgr:id="Subclass1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
      <Department>10</Department>
      <Category>03</Category>
      <Class>010</Class>
      <Subclass>03</Subclass>
      <SubclassLongDescription>BABY ACCESSORIES-OTHER LD TX 1120</SubclassLongDescription>
      <SubclassShortDescription>BABY ACCESSORIES-OTH</SubclassShortDescription>
    </Subclass>
  </diffgr:before>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

I don't want anything but those department and DepartmentDescription tags. Why are the other nodes MessageHeader/subclass being copied when they are not specified in the xslt?

Can anyone give me a better solution than above. It's pretty tedious to add every node like this but works if nothing else possible.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use an identity transform, with a special rule for handling `<Department>` elements that lets you specify which of its children you want to copy. Here is some sample code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Department[Department]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Department|DepartmentDescription" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I get using the data in your *update* looks like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">

   <NewDataSet>

      <Department diffgr:id="Department1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
         <Department>10</Department>
         <DepartmentDescription>BABY PRODUCTS</DepartmentDescription>
      </Department>

   </NewDataSet>

</diffgr:diffgram>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have 2 issues with this xslt
1. I lose the attributes of Department
2. If there are more nodes on the same level of Department(siblings), they are still copied. Can I not have a simple xslt that just copies what I want...?

Comment: @mdfaraz I have amended my answer to deal with the attributes. I'm not sure what you mean about siblings of `<Department>`. If you mean the *inner* element by that name then it works fine for me and includes only `Department/Department` and `Department/Department`. If you mean the first-level Department element, then neither your data nor your question mentioned any siblings and I assumed you wanted to keep everything else as it was. Please explain.

Comment: @mdfaraz: **edit** In my comment above I meant `Department/Department` and `Department/DepartmentDescription`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only match specific nodes, as opposed to providing a list of exclusions, you could just enter a list of element names you require

```
<xsl:template match="Department|DepartmentSeq|InsertDateTime|@*">
```

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="Department|DepartmentSeq|InsertDateTime|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML (I've removed namespace prefixes for simplification)

```
<Department id="Department1" rowOrder="0">
   <Department>10</Department>
   <DepartmentDescription>BABY PRODUCTS</DepartmentDescription>
   <DepartmentSeq>7</DepartmentSeq>
   <InsertDateTime>2011-09-29T13:19:28.817-05:00</InsertDateTime>
</Department>
```

The following is output. Do note that attributes are retained by means of the @* match.

```
<Department id="Department1" rowOrder="0">
   <Department>10</Department>
   <DepartmentSeq>7</DepartmentSeq>
   <InsertDateTime>2011-09-29T13:19:28.817-05:00</InsertDateTime>
</Department>
```

Do note the use of the following template match, which will exclude all elements not in your matching list. Without this, the default behaviour would be to output the text value of the element

```
<xsl:template match="*" />
```

Comment: The snippet I sent was from a .NET Diffgram

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked best for my input

```
<xsl:template match="diffgr:diffgram|diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet|diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet/Department|diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet/Department/Department|diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet/Department/DepartmentDescription|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I found that having to write a match for each node in the hierarchy is very cumbersome. Still works though, better solutions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/><xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- shutup unwanted elements -->
  <xsl:template match="MessageHeader
        | Subclass
        | InsertDateTime
        | UpdateDateTime
        | InsertDateTimeUTC
        | DepartmentSeq
        | diffgr:before"/>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```